# httplib HTTP class for python3?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.5, httplib

I want to convert following python2 code to python3 code.
The bottom line is my problem.

```
from httplib import HTTP
```

I don't know what code should i replace that and `from http.client import HTTP` will not work.

```
from httplib import HTTP
from httplib import HTTPConnection
from socket import socket

USE_UNIX_SOCKETS = False

try:
    from socket import AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM
    USE_UNIX_SOCKETS = True
except ImportError:
    pass

if (USE_UNIX_SOCKETS):

    class UnixHTTPConnection(HTTPConnection):
        def connect(self):
            self.sock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM)
            self.sock.connect(self.host)

    class UnixHTTP(HTTP):
        _connection_class = UnixHTTPConnection

    class UnixTransport(TransportMixIn, XMLTransport):

        def make_connection(self, host):
            host, extra_headers, x509 = self.get_host_info(host)
            return UnixHTTP(host)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html), The HTTP class is retained only for backward compatibility with 1.5.2. It should not be used in new code.
So I should Change my code.